# Brownian Motion infinitesimal generator $\int Lf(x) \mu(dx) = 0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Take $B(t)$ as a standard Brownian Motion.

> Consider a real-valued Markov process with infinitesimal generator L.
>   Recall that µ is an invariant measure if $$\int E[f(B(t))] \mu(dx) =
>  \int f(x) \mu(dx)$$ for any bounded measurable function $f$ and all $t
> > 0$.
>
> Prove that $$\int Lf(x) \mu(dx) = 0$$ for functions $f$ in the domain
>   of $L$.

I need some help with this problem. I know that $E[B(t)]=0$ but it seems like unless $f$ is linear, I cannot make the jump to $E[f(B(t))]=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $\mu$-invariance we have $\int (E^x f(B(h))-f(x))\mu(dx) = 0$ for all $h>0$ hence using dominated convergence
$$
\int L f(x) \mu(dx) = \lim_{h\to 0} h^{-1}\int (E^x f(B(h))-f(x))\mu(dx) = 0.
$$

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.